# richTextbox color of XML File

Tags: xml, winforms, richtextbox

I have a `string` that is actually an XML.

I am using a procedure that gives me the `string` in a formatted way but I also want to have it colorized within the `richTextBox`. The procedure I am using now is

```
private void beautify()
{
    //   richTextBox1.HideSelection = false;

    richTextBox1.BackColor = Color.White;
    richTextBox1.SelectAll();

    richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.IndianRed;

    int firstLine = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf('\n', 1);

    HighlightText(richTextBox1, "<", Color.Blue,true);
    HighlightText(richTextBox1, ">", Color.Blue,true);
    HighlightText(richTextBox1, "=", Color.Blue,true);
    HighlightText(richTextBox1, "\"", Color.Blue,true);
    HighlightText(richTextBox1, "</", Color.Blue,true);
    HighlightText(richTextBox1, "=>", Color.Blue, true);

    string[] str = richTextBox1.Text.Split('\u0022');
    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
    {
        if(i%2 != 0)
        HighlightText(richTextBox1, str[i], Color.Black,false);
    }

    richTextBox1.Select(0, firstLine);
    richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
}
```

It mostly works with some bugs, but my biggest problem is that for very large XML it is taking way too long. I was wondering if there is a library or something else to handle this faster.

Comment: Consider using [Fast Colored TextBox](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/161871/Fast-Colored-TextBox-for-syntax-highlighting).

Comment: This exactly what I needed. Thank you!